# Color Resources do not work. and content is not allowed in prolog (Error)

Tags: android, android-resources

i am using from android Studio but i don't know problem. so i searched in stack overflow but not useful ...
please Help  ...

> Error color.xml [image]
>
> I:\New folder\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content
>   is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: @S.L. Barth - but this link, doesn't work for me . are you have a good way for my problem

Comment: remove those character and write its content in usual way

Comment: OK, I've retracted the close-vote. Sorry to hear that post didn't help.

Comment: @ ashad  ----- but has error, i  when time remove characters Error: Premature end of file.

Comment: @S.L. Barth -- ok , if you good way .plese say me that what  i do

Comment: If I had a good way, I'd have told you. All I can do now is wish you best of luck.

Comment: @S.L. Barth - ok if i found it , be sure that i share in this page

Comment: You found the solution? That's good to hear! If it was the answer by jsRook below, you should click the checkmark next to their answer. If it was something different, please post it as your own answer. Either way, congratulations on solving the issue!

Comment: @S.L. Barth -- ok  sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like the content in color.xml was not in proper as usual format . the content in the auto generated color.xml file has colors value fore project.

for  fix,copy and paste this code in color.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

if the contnet in the color.xml file is always gone like this whenever you create new android studio project ,then fix will be :-  
1)click on new file, Invalidate Cache/Restart 
 
  if not then reinstall android studio

Comment: what you trying to say

Comment: @ jsRook -- my erros in console when time  i use this way   is :  Android resource compilation failed

Comment: @ jsRook -- yes just , i did it ..but now has exist Error